# Add custom task to Moodle cron job

Tags: php, cron, moodle

I'm working with Moodle 2.9, and trying to add some new task to cron. 
Inside my `moodle/theme/portal` folder I added a `portal_cron()` function to `lib.php` file, then I run cron manually from command line but it's not working ?! 

Cron work normally but ignored my new task! 
So what I'm doing wrong and how can I add new task to cron ?

Comment: It would help if you could please paste config, function, code etc. along with error/stack trace. What exactly are you trying to  achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, 
Just changed the function name from `portal_cron()` to `theme_portal_cron()` in `lib.php`, because this file is in `moodle/theme/portal/lib.php` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a cron value in `moodle/theme/portal/version.php` eg:

```
$plugin->cron = 60; // Every 60 seconds.
```

Although the cron function is still available, you should use scheduled tasks from Moodle 2.7+

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Task_API

Comment: Yes I've set `$plugin->cron = 60;`

Comment: Is there any way to check if cron see my new task, or if my new task is working or not ? I mean if I can echo some output or something ?

Comment: yes, you can use `mtrace('my plugin is working')` then check the output when running cron. From a browser you can run `[url]/admin/cron.php`